# Double quote escaping with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

JSON.stringify escapes double quotes. Is there an input such that the following code (without modification) does not result in the escape of the double quotes?

```
<script>
function test(s) {
document.write(JSON.stringify(s));
}
</script>


  <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="test(this.cmd.value); return false;">
  <input class="command" type="text" id="cmdbox" name="cmd" />
  </form>
```

Example input/output:

```
"test"
```

Expected:

```
"test"
```

Actual:

```
\"test\"
```

Comment: You want to change something without doing anything???

Comment: The code I posted creates an input box input is sent to the function and writes the result to the page. Is there an INPUT string containing double quotes that results in double quotes not being escaped..

Comment: Double quotes are necessary to get a valid JSON Object "A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested." written on http://www.json.org/

Comment: See: \"test\". What input can be given to avoid the commenting out of the double quotes

Comment: Or in other words, can JSON.stringify be passed a value in the form above such that the result if it contains double quotes are not commented out.

Comment: @OBV Yes ist's possible with the second stringify param https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter but inside that function you have to unescabe/decode ist again or need a RegExp to remove \" and i'#s more code reqired compared to given answear

Answer (score 2):

Use to unescape the escaped string to get the expected result.

```
unescape(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: "(without modification)"

Comment: `escape` and `unescape` are deprecated. Use `encodeURI` and `decodeURI`.

Comment: Thanks I will remember for future ;)